# How to fill between x and two functions (intersection)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, intersection, fuzzy

How can I fill the intersection between two functions?

I have this:

[image]

I need the intersection between f1 and f2 (min(f1, f2)). Like this:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array(np.linspace(0, 10, 1000))
f1 = eval('-x+10')
f2 = eval('x')
plt.plot(x, f1, label='f1')
plt.plot(x, f2, label='f2')
plt.fill_between(x, f1, f2, alpha=.5)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem reduces to being able to find elementwise minimum of `f1` and `f2`. Numpy has [`numpy.minimum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html) that does exactly this. So the following code gives the desired plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array(np.linspace(0, 10, 1000))
f1 = eval('-x+10')
f2 = eval('x')
f3 = np.minimum(f1, f2)
plt.plot(x, f1, label='f1')
plt.plot(x, f2, label='f2')
plt.fill_between(x, f3, alpha=.5)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]